# Different DPI for different screens stopped to work on Ubuntu 18/04

Tags: multiple-monitors, dpi, hdpi

On Ubuntu 17.10 I was able to use different DPIs on my internal monitor and external one - 200% for QHD+ internal and 100% for FHD external. Now when I try to switch percent value on either of the monitors I get the other one switched as well.

Does anyone know how to change screen DPIs separately on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the reason was that Ubuntu 18.04 switched back to Xorg as a default and 17.10 had Wayland as default display server. It appears that Xorg doesn't support different DPIs for different screens and Wayland does.

So the solution is: use Wayland - you can choose it on login screen.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS silently overrides your choice to Xorg. Even though Wayland works better in most cases.

Comment: Scaling makes a lot of apps blurry in Wayland. As long as you never use Chrome or Firefox, Wayland is the way to go...

Comment: Chrome worked for me just fine actually.

Comment: For me, Chrome and Firefox are both blurry on Wayland (with multiple monitors), but not on Xorg.